# корректное написание слова

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно выразиться: очистка поверхности медных сплавов или чистка? или чистка применима в употреблении выражения чистка медных сплавов, а очистка к поверхности? спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Чистка - это обычно общее название процесса удаления загрязнений, вредных веществ, а очистка - название процесса более целенаправленного (очистка от конкретных загрязнений). **В некоторых случаях эти слова употребляются как синонимы, в других - сочетаемость избирательная.**

Примеры

1) Чистка склонов не проводилась десять лет. Чистка помещения затягивалась на надолго. Чистка пуговиц на кителе была обязательной  операцией.  Чистка обуви, зубов, одежды.

2) Очистка от сорняков, очистка вод от тяжелых металлов, воздуха от пыли, организма от токсинов.

РЕШЕНИЕ

Возможны такие варианты: чистка медных монет, чистка/очистка поверхности медных сплавов, средство для очистки поверхности меди и ее сплавов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Корректны оба варианта. См. значение в словаре.

***ОЧИСТИТЬ, -*** св. 1. (нсв. также чистить). что. ***Удалить грязь или другое наслоение; сделать чистым.*** О. одежду от снега. ***О. ржавчину***. О. ковёр от пыли.

***ЧИСТИТЬ,*** - нсв. кого-что. 1. (св. вычистить). ***Удаляя грязь, пыль, ржавчину, окислы и т.п. с кого-, чего-л., делать чистым; очищать.*** Ч. зубы. Ч. ковёр пылесосом. Ч. щёткой платье. Ч. коня. Ч. сапоги. Ч. кастрюли.

***Толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова.***

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

В русском язвке - да, возможны оба существительных с близкими значениями и без существенных особенностей в употреблении.

Но тут есть один существенный момент. Если это терминологические единицы (а скорее всего так оно и есть, ибо текст узкопрофессиональный), то надо смотреть или спрашивать в источниках тоже профессиональных, чтобы не попасть впросак.

Я, не будучи профессионалом, интуитивно подозреваю, что Ваша идея насчет поверхности и объемного процесса не лишена оснований. Только наоборот. Поверхность чистят (сравните: "химчистка", чистка зубов и проч.), а вот содержание очищают (очистка сточных вод, "служил в Очистке" - *про Шарикова*). Единственное исключение из истории - "чистка кадров", но это переносное значение, да и язык не слишком изысканный.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о технологической операции, то "очистка" уместнее, покольку, в отличие от "чистки", обозначает **результативное** действие. Логичнее добиться очистки (очищенного состояния, т.е. когда *очистка* произошла) поверхности и перейти к следующей операции, чем почистить поверхность запланированное время (произвести чистку) и напр. покрасить, не обращая внимания на результат.

Comment: Очень спорно. Вообще в русском языке "результативность действия" определяется более свойствами самого глагола, нежели приставки. А приставка О менее всего означает результативность. наряду с !ПО" и какой-то еще, "ИЗ", кажется. Омыть, оправить, огладить (все - семантические близкие к очистить). Ну где здесь "результативность"?

Comment: Здесь значение слова следует не из его структурных признаков, а из практики употребления в подобных предложенному контекстах. В глагольной форме даже с приставкой, придающей совершенный вид, слово "почистить" в применении напр. к картошке результативно, поскольку имеет смысл "срезать кожуру", а в отношении поверхности - нет: можно почистить её несколькими способами и не добиться очистки от ржавчины, прочих окислов, смазки и т.п. Приставка "по" позволяет прекратить начатое действие, но не гарантирует результата. А очистить поверхность от чего-то - однозначно это что-то удалить.

Comment: Согласен почти со всем, кроме последней фразы (однозначно). Ну да бог с ним. Мы, видимо, совершенно по-разному понимаем "результативность". В отношении картошки и поверхности - совсем спорно даже само утверждение о результативности.  Но главная ошибка в том, что это не практика использования, это разная семантика приставки. Таких примеров с ПО можно миллион придумать. "Подумать" - это поделать что-то (как почитать, поплавать) или совершить действие (как помыться, побриться)? Два омонимичных значения приставки - два значения глагола. Я так это вижу. А по сути исходного вопроса добавить нечего.

Comment: спасибо большое! очень доступно объяснили

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вы не расплав чистите от примесей. Я бы сказал - чистка изделий из медных сплавов (или даже меди и её сплавов, если медные чистите тоже). Очистка поверхности несколько громоздко и потому менее ясно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!